# /tmp directory size in Fedora

Tags: fedora, tmpfs

I am using Fedora 26 and have some troubles with /tmp on tmpfs. By default Fedora sets the /tmp size to a half of RAM size. In my case it is 4/2=2GB. But I noticed this causes faults during some software updates which need to unzip large distribution files.

I have set the /tmp size to 4GB and it solves the problem but I am not sure that was the right strategy, because it is looking stupid to fulfill the unzip task in the single step using all the RAM available and crash when reaching the limit.

Comment: Use swap partition/file.

Comment: Swap is on, but unzipping is limited by temp size, not swap

Comment: tmpfs can use swap.

Comment: Which software is causing the problem? Can you get it to use `/var/tmp` instead?

Comment: OMG, 6 years passed and I cannot not remember this question of mine )))) During this time I learned it is default behavoiur of systemd and many distros affected. To switch it off and make tmp regular directory like in Windows it's need to issue this command: sudo systemctl mask tmp.mount

Answer (score 12):

Issuing `# mount -o remount,size=4G,noatime /tmp` when you need to do large file operations, adjusting size to fit the task, is one of the correct strategies in your situation, along with being the simplest solution.
It will revert to normal on next reboot.

More information, including how to make this permanent, can be found here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmpfs